# Caffe: Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (48 vs. 0) no kernel image is available for execution on the device error on Jetson TX1

Tags: caffe

I was able to successfully compile Caffe on a Nvidia Jetson TX1 board with CUDA 9.0 and Open CV 3.

However, when I run the following command to test Caffe:

```
build/tools/caffe time --model=models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt --gpu=0
```

I get the following error:

```
F0712 23:05:53.664676 28580 im2col.cu:61]  Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (48 vs. 0)  no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

If I remove the `--gpu=0` flag, I don't see the error anymore.

Any help/suggestions on how I can get the code to use the GPU will be much appreciated.

Comment: I got the same problem. Expecting some one to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have the cuda arch number correct in the MakeFile.config with respect to the jetson architecture, sth like this:

```
-gencode arch=compute_72,code=sm_72 \
```